# Datepicker item is not getting refresh

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have created two items in oracle apex to pass min date and maximum which will get select on basis of items which are select list which selects and returns year, and passing those minimum value and maximum value from min and max item into a `date_picker` to specify a range in `date_picker` but it's not refreshing the `date_picker` item.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help),and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) and create [mcve] if possible

Comment: this kind of sounds to me as if you are expecting the date picker to refresh after you set the dates? This ain't gonna happen with apex since you have to submit those items to the DB first.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how you specified those min/max values in date picker item. Should be e.g.

```
&P1_MIN_DATE.
```

- note leading ampersand `&` and trailing dot `.` characters!

If it doesn't help, please, create a page on apex.oracle.com, provide credentials so that we could have a look what you did, how Apex responded and - hopefully - assist.